# Is there any ThreadStatic attribute for parent and child threads

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

Is there any attribute or some method of sharing a value between a thread and the background workers it creates?

I am making a SQL Server CLR assembly that does a search in the database + some calculations, and I want it to be multi threading. I need to share some data between the calling thread and the background workers I create (what is read from the calling thread from database, I want to be passed to the workers, so that they compute what I need).

I don't think that sending a class object as parameter to the RunWorkerAsync is a good idea, since inside the threads I use lock(item); and Interlocked.Add(ref itemCount, -1); mechanism.

What I also need, is that if another search call is made, the values from these 2 call stacks are not mixed up.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you think passing a parameter to the thread is a bad idea? Provide some code as well. That usually draws more interest.

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass an Int variable. And variables are copied, right? since they are not pointers to a class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ThreadStatic variables like you want, you might consider passing your integer as a parameter, but instead of passing it raw, wrap it in a holder object.

```
class ResultHolder
{
    public int result;
}
```

You can then use the object to hold your int by reference.

```
Thread t = new Thread(Run);
var holder = new ResultHolder() { result = 0x92 }
t.Start(holder);

// Query the result
Console.WriteLine(holder.result);
```